# fog and dyn destroy record

Tags: ruby, dns, fog

I'm currently using Fog to manage Dyn DNS provider. According the documentation, there's a `destroy` method on the DNS record object. However, when I call `destroy`, on a record, nothing happens... the method just returns true, but it is never deleted. Here's the code I'm using:

```
@dynect = Fog::DNS.new(
  :provider => "dynect",
  :dynect_customer => "CUSTOMER",
  :dynect_username => "USERNAME",
  :dynect_password => 'PASSWORD'
)

@zone = @dynect.zones.get('zone.example.com')
@record = @zone.records.find{|r| r.name == 'master.zone.example.com' && r.type == 'CNAME'}
@record.destroy
@zone.save
```

This will return true, but nothing ever happens - the DNS record still exists on Dyn.

How do I delete a record with Fog and Dyn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to then publish (not save) the zone... This is not obvious, since other providers, like AWS, don't require. Here's an updated code snippet:

```
@dynect = Fog::DNS.new(
  :provider => "dynect",
  :dynect_customer => "CUSTOMER",
  :dynect_username => "USERNAME",
  :dynect_password => 'PASSWORD'
)

@zone = @dynect.zones.get('zone.example.com')
@record = @zone.records.find{|r| r.name == 'master.zone.example.com' && r.type == 'CNAME'}
@record.destroy
@zone.publish # changed this
```